# StageText and Emoji on Android - AIR Mobile - AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, emoji

I have a big problem and can't find anything about it online.

Using **Flex**/**Air Mobile** I do a simple thing, using 2  components:

> txt2.text = txt1.text;

If **txt1.text** contains **emoji**, they are not taken to txt2. Instead, it creates a mess with weird characters.

What kills me is that when you type it, the emoji are shown correctly. When I capture the value and trace it, the emoji appear on Flash Builder's console (in OSX) correctly, but when you set the value of another StageText (I tried it with `raw` StageText, created from code to avoid any other class or code from interfering)

Right now I met a dead end, no ideas of what else to do...and I have to release to Android a chatting app that's working like a charm on iOS, and I have this problem.

Ideas? Please?

Comment: How did you show your emoji in your first text field ? Is that an image, an embedded font, ... ?

Comment: Didn't see this answer before. Sorry.
I just typed in the emoji via android keyboard. It's a stagetext.

Comment: Have you compared the `.htmlText` attribute? Have you tried copying .htmlText to .htmlText?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
txt2.text = decodeURI(txt1.text);
```

but I am afraid this is because StageText use a native input textfield that on iOS is able to reach the Apple Color Emoji font that is not available on Android

Comment: But Android has it's own emoji keyboard and font too, right? It's able to type in emoji and show it on screen.
Since it's kinda old, I'll have to check again if the problem persists, but tks for your time anyways! ;)